# Mongoose array parameter filter

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

Let's assume I have the following model in mongoose:

```
var Product = new Schema({
   eanCode: String,
   brandName: String,
   productNameNl: String,
   sex: String,
   suggestedRetailPrice: Number
})
```

How can I write a function to query this model using an array with parameters? I want a generic function which can get anything from this model using an array of filter parameters. For example:

```
var filterArray = [
    sex: "gents",
    brand: "brandName"
];
var fieldsArray = ["sex", "brand", "productNameNl", "eanCode"];
var getBrandGentsProducts = getProducts(filterArray);

function getProducts(fields, filter){
    Product.Find({fields}, {filter}).exec(function(err, products){
       return products;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your fieldArray to build key value pair for your filter

Example:

```
// create a filterMap for your fields and value that you want to filter with
var filterMap = {
    sex: "gents",
    brand: "brandName"
}; 
var fieldsArray = ["sex", "brand", "productNameNl", "eanCode"];
var getBrandGentsProducts = getProducts(filterArray);

function mapFilter(fields, filter) {
  return fieldsArray.reduce(function (obj, field) {
    if (filterMap[field]) {
      obj[field] = filterMap[field];
    }
    return obj;
  }, {});  
}
function getProducts(fields, filter){
    var filterPair = mapFilter(fields, filter);
    //console.log(filterPair) //output { "brand": "brandName", "sex": "gents" }
    Product.Find(filterPair).exec(function(err, products){
       return products;
    })
}
```